# Событие, привязанное к кнопке в Tkinter срабатывает уже в момент привязки

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

l1 = Label(text = 'Just Label')
b1 = Button(text = 'Click me!')

def change(a):
    if a['text'] == 'Just changed label1':
        a['text'] == 'Just changed label2'
    else:
        a['text'] = 'Just changed label1'
    return a

b1.config(command=change(l1))

l1.pack()
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

При запуске программы кнопка не работает, а label уже изменён, будто я нажал один раз на кнопку. В других случаях, когда я применяю функцию при работе с tkinter, происходит абсолютно тоже самое. В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что у вас функция выполняется уже в этой строке:

```
b1.config(command=change(l1))
```

Чтобы не выполнить функцию, а передать её в качестве аргумента, нужно написать её без скобок:

```
b1.config(command=change)
```

Но в этом случае у вас функция никак не узнает, что ей нужно именно с лэйблом `l1` работать, и это нужно как-то отдельно решать.

Например, можно сделать так:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

l1 = Label(text='Just Label')
b1 = Button(text='Click me!')


def change_factory(a):
    def change():
        if a['text'] == 'Just changed label1':
            a['text'] = 'Just changed label2'
        else:
            a['text'] = 'Just changed label1'
        return
    return change


b1.config(command=change_factory(l1))

l1.pack()
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

В этом случае у вас есть фабрика change_factory, которая получает на вход аргумент label и создаёт функцию change, которая с помощью такой штуки как **замыкание** уже настроена именно на этот лэйбл.

После этого в строке

```
b1.config(command=change_factory(l1))
```

у вас эта фабрика отрабатывает, создаёт нужную `change` и уже этот нужный `change` передаётся в качестве аргумента `command`

Comment: Можно без вложенных функций: `b1.config(command=lambda label=l1: change(label))`

Comment: Или с помощью [частичного применения](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial): `b1.config(command=partial(change, label))`

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

l1 = Label(text = 'Just Label')


def change(a):
    if a['text'] == 'Just changed label1':
        a['text'] == 'Just changed label2'
    else:
        a['text'] = 'Just changed label1'
    return a
def onClick():
    b1.config(command=change(l1))
b1 = Button(text = 'Click me!',command=onClick)
l1.pack()
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```